# How casting out $11$s works?

Tags: arithmetic

Following line are quoted from the book *Secrets of Mental Math* by *Arthur Benjamin 
and
Michael Shermer*.

> To double-check your answer another way, you can use the
>   method known as casting out elevens. It’s similar to casting out
>   nines, except you reduce the numbers by alternately subtracting
>   and adding the digits from right to left, ignoring any decimal
>   point. If the result is negative, then add eleven to it. (It may be
>   tempting to do the addition and subtraction from left to right,
>   as you do with mod sums, but in this case you must do it from
>   right to left for it to work.)
>   For example:
>   [image]
>
> The same method works for subtraction problems:
>   [image]

How can we explain why this method works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basis idea is 
$$ 10 \equiv -1 \pmod{11} $$
That is, for a natural number $a = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k10^k$, we have
$$ a \equiv \sum_{k=0}^n a_k (-1)^k = a_0 - a_1 \pm \cdots + (-1)^k a_k \pmod{11} $$
That is, both $a$ and the alternating sum have the same remainder modulo eleven. As addition and subtraction works well modulo eleven, this method checks if the remainders modulo eleven are correct.

Comment: Is that $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k10^k = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k (-1)^k$ at your point of view; or something else?
I couldn't understand why you have stated $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k (-1)^k$ here.